# Linux: Secondary default gateway for VPN connection to provide internet access

Tags: routing, gateway, routing-table

#### Background:

There are several devices/computers in an isolated network to which I have access using SSH, but which can not access the internet. To temporarily bypass this restriction for installing updates and related tasks, I create an SSH reverse tunnel using my machine to give those machines the ability to connect to an OpenVPN server, which then allows them to access the internet. This works fine up to the point that the machines have a tun interface for the VPN.

#### Configuration

The remote machine has a single physical Ethernet interface with a static private IP address. Example: 192.168.56.101/24. The interface has set a router in the isolated network as default gateway, e.g. 192.168.56.1. My own machine also has a private IP address, but is not in the same subnet. Example: 192.168.30.30. When I open the VPN connection on the remote machine, it gets a tun0 interface with an IP like 10.88.0.10/16. The VPN server can be reached as 10.88.0.1, which will route the traffic to the internet.

#### Challenge

When I establish the VPN connection, the remote machine must "know" that it should use the VPN interface for all traffic relating to the internet. However, it must still use the original Ethernet for the SSH connection to my machine or I'm locked out.

What I'm basically after is something like having two default gateways:

1. The original default gateway, which allows the connection to my machine, plus everything else in the isolated network. It should be used for all private destination addresses, except for the VPN network (10.88.0.0/16).
2. The VPN interface, which provides internet access. This should be used for all traffic not directed to a private network. Addresses like 8.8.8.8 (Google nameserver) should be routed through this interface/gateway.

#### Question

How do I need to configure the routes on the remote machine for such a scenario? Is there something like an "exception" for the default gateway, to tell the computer to use the gateway for everything except some private addresses/networks?

Comment: I don't think you need two default routes (and policy routing). Having the IP of the remote ssh is enough to add a specific route to it. As SSH exports a few variables like SSH_CLIENT or SSH_CONNECTION this should be scriptable.

Comment: There are other resources in the 192.168.56.0/24, which should stay accessible as well. But it would probably work by just manually adding a static route for this whole network.